# vb.net chart candlesticks are cut in half when scrolling

Tags: vb.net, charts

I have my candlestick chart in vb.net looking the way I want it to, however, when the candles are displayed and I use the horizontal scrollbar the candles on either end of the chart are cut in half.

I've tried multiple settings within the chart series and chart areas but keep getting the same result.

Here is what it looks like currently

Candles cut in half:

[image]

Comment: Isn't that exactly how it should look?

Comment: If you continue scrolling, do you get the full-width candlesticks?

Comment: I do get the full width candles with the scrollbar on the extreme far left or far right. However,  I added 0.5 to one of the scale settings which will now show the full bar on the right side of the chart while scrolling with just the bars on the left cut off.

Comment: It seems that this is how the control your are using works. That is, it shows partial candlesticks when scrolling. There might be settings in your control that tell "to never show partial candlesticks when scrolling". If not, extend the control to do so, or use a different control that has that setting.